# I can not find the error discord.js giphy/hug command

Tags: javascript, discord.js, giphy

```
const GphApiClient = require("giphy-js-sdk-core");
var giphy = GphApiClient ;
exports.run =  (bot, message, args, client) => {

giphy.search("gifs", { q: "fail" })
    .then(response => {
      var totalResponses = response.data.length;
      var responseIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1) % totalResponses;
      var responseFinal = response.data[responseIndex]


 const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed() // Here is my problem it says 'Discord' is not defined
  .setAuthor('x')
  .setColor('RANDOM')
  .setTimestamp()
  .setDescription('')
  .setImage(responseFinal.images.fixed_height.url)        
  message.channel.send(embed)
}
)
}


exports.conf = {
enabled: true,
guildOnly: false,
aliases: [],
permLevel: 0
};

exports.help = {
name: 'hug',
description: 'Free Hug!',
usage: 'hug'
};
```

I need help :c I just started to coding. I dont know what's the error it just says

> 'Discord' is not defined

If you find the error please dm me on discord.
Wanheda#2722

Answer (score 0):

You need to `require` discord.js:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
// rest of code...
```

> I dont know what's the error

The error is `'Discord' is not defined`, which means that Node.js saw `Discord` in `Discord.RichEmbed` and tried to get its value, but there is no variable `Discord`.

See [ReferenceError: "x" is not defined on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_defined).